# Convert.ToSingle(string) C# conversion ambiguity

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
string x = "-0.228469369833477";

Single s = Convert.ToSingle(x);

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The console outputs: -2,284694E+14 .

What can I do to make it output: -0.228469369833477?

Comment: What culture is used?

Comment: i don't think a single will hold that much precision.

Comment: It looks like your culture is using comma for the decimal point, so parsing that number will not recognize the period as a decimal separator.

Comment: "Value as is"? Please, at least go through http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Indeed - [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx): "A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally."

Comment: @Luaan: You don't need to know all that to simply know that `single` has insufficient precision.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No. But you do need that to know that binary floating point numbers don't care about decimal digits. If you do, you most likely don't want to use a binary floating point number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Single s = Single.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want it to output that exact number, you can't use a [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) because it doesn't give you the precision you want. Try using a double.

```
double s = Double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

To output the number in its original form:

```
var s = -0.228469369833477;
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("0.#######################"));
```

Note that `s` is likely a `double`, not a `single`.  By using `single` you're very likely losing digits.  To get enough precision to represent all of the digits, use `Convert.ToDouble()` instead.

To ensure that the number gets parsed properly in your locale, use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as other answers have stated.

A `decimal` will give you 28-29 significant digits of precision, with better precision and without the scientific notation problems.

**Further Reading**
[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'd say that once you care about the individual decimal digits, the number is arguably a `decimal`. It's hard to tell what exactly the OP needs, though.

Comment: I agree that if the aim is just to output as it is, your method would work.. Since the precision required is 15 digit, `double` would also be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `'.'` is treated as a *thousand* separator (and `','` as *decimal* one) in your *current culture* (e.g. Russian Culture - `"RU-ru"` works like that) and since *thousand* separator ignored on conversion you have `-228469369833477` (or `-2,284694E+14`).

```
string x = "-0.228469369833477";

// To ensure that '.' is treated as decimal separator
// lets put culture explicitly - CultureInfo.InvariantCulture 
Single s = Convert.ToSingle(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

However, you have *too many* digits to represent for a `Single` and all you can return is `-0.2284694` (not `-0.228469369833477`). If you want exact correspondence you have to use `Double` instead of `Single`:

```
Double s = Convert.ToDouble(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// -0.228469369833477
Console.WriteLine(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N8}", s));
```

to output the single to 8 decimal places.

You can also specify the culture while doing the string formatting:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N8}", s));
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nS9qXh

Comment: He wants the complete number, not just 8 decimal places.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That was an example. He can change the N8 to any value. N9 outputs to 9 decimal places. Besides as far as i know, the single is stored internally to a maximum of 9 decimal places.

Comment: That's still not enough to represent the entire number.

Comment: If he wants it to 15 decimal places all he has to do is use N15. If he wants to to 50 decimal places, then use N50. It's not that difficult to deduce from my example.

Comment: `Single` will only support 7 to 9 digits of precision, no matter how many digits you try to coerce from it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my second comment. Thanks for agreeing.

Comment: You're welcome.  My point is, it doesn't answer the question that was asked, unless you squint.